# Why does casting using "as" operator result in the casted object being null with C# dynamics

Tags: c#, .net

For example,

Lets say group.SupportedProducts is ["test", "hello", "world"]

```
var products = (string[]) group.SupportedProducts;
```

results in "products" correctly being a string array which contains the above 3 elements - "test", "hello" and "world"

However,

```
var products= group.SupportedProducts as string[];
```

results in products being null.

Comment: @zerkms that means you disagree the first statement "works" (I hate that verb in questions)

Comment: @Shmiddty Arrays aren't primitives right?

Comment: @zerkms That's like Q. "why is the steering wheel on the left in UK cars?" A. "because American cars have automatic gearboxes and you need a driver's license." It's all true, but it has no relation

Comment: @C.Evenhuis: I hate only the negation "doesn't work".

Comment: Thanks for the feedback everyone. Edited the question so it makes more sense. Please read now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Presumably `group.SupportedProducts` isn't *actually* a `string[]`, but it's something which supports a custom conversion to `string[]`.

`as` *never* invokes custom conversions, whereas casting does.

Sample to demonstrate this:

```
using System;

class Foo
{
    private readonly string name;

    public Foo(string name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static explicit operator string(Foo input)
    {
        return input.name;
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        dynamic foo = new Foo("name");
        Console.WriteLine("Casting: {0}", (string) foo);
        Console.WriteLine("As: {0}", foo as string);
    }
}
```

Comment: Whoa. Mind blown. I dismissed user defined conversions alltogether because OP said the thing was `dynamic`. I thought UDC were never considered unless at compile time (i.e. not in generic settings)